# ¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a Jenkins que me dé como válidos unos resultados erróneos de un test de Postman?

Tags: postman, jenkins

tengo unas colecciones de Postman integradas en Jenkins que se ejecutan con un comando de newman. Mi caso es que tengo unos tests que me tienen que fallar para ver que la API me da un error que necesito. Y me preguntaba si existe alguna forma de decirle a Jenkins que si me devuelve dicho error, me dé válido el test y no como error en el reporte de Postman, concretamente en el plugin: "Postman Report".

Answer (score 1):

¿Has pensado en usar una prueba dentro del propio postman, de manera que captures el error, y si es el error que esperas, entonces, la prueba funcione?

Esto tiene la ventaja que desacoplas las pruebas del pipeline, y configuras todas las posibilidades en el postman y en el pipeline solo esperas que todos los test estén OK.

En la imagen estoy haciendo la prueba de una página que no existe. Es decir, que la prueba correcta es que de error 404. Aunque el postman recibe un error 404, la prueba pasa exitosamente. Creo que esto pudieras usarlo para tú caso

[image: Ejemplo de test en postman]